# How can I duplicate a row in DataTables (jQuery DataTables plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I found out how to delete a row with this jQuery code. While clicking on a td with the class delete and a garbage icon.

HTML

```
<table id="foo" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>Foo1</td>
      <td>Foo2</td>
      <td>Foo3</td>
      <td class="delete">IMAGE src here</td>
      <td><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#foo tbody').on( 'click', 'tr .delete', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
    } );
```

But I did not find anything about duplicating rows. I just want to click on a td with another icon in it and the row is duplicated below.

Comment: what do you want to remove exactly?

Comment: Hi, i dont want to remove anything. I already can remove rows. I want to DUPLICATE rows when i click on a, for example <td> field.

Comment: Do you want to delete a row or duplicate a row?

Comment: something like this should work
$('#foo tbody').on( 'click', 'tr .duplicate', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeIn("slow", function(){
            $(this).clone().appendTo($( this) )
        })
    } );

Comment: @twernt, i want to duplicate a row.. delete is already working :)

Comment: You might want like this. Check out this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bikashm/2f6zoh0o/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To duplicate a row, you'll need to copy all of its data into an array, then call [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) to insert this data as a new row.

Something like:

```html
<table id="foo" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>Foo1</td>
      <td>Foo2</td>
      <td>Foo3</td>
      <td class="delete">IMAGE src here</td>
      <td class="copy">IMAGE src here</td>
      <td><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```js
$('#foo tbody').on( 'click', 'tr .copy', function () {
  var row_data = [];
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function() {
    row_data.push($(this).text());
  });
  // you'll need a reference to your DataTable here
  table.row.add(row_data).draw();
});
```

To get a reference to your DataTable, assign the result of the `DataTable()` method to a var.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var table = $('#foo).DataTable( { "paging": false, "info": false }); 
  // set up your event handlers, etc. 
});
```

If you append a row with jQuery instead of DataTables method like `row.add()`, you'll lose the row when you sort or page the table.

Comment: Like this ? 

 $('#bega-data-tables tbody').on( 'click', 'tr .copy', function () {
            var row_data = [];
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function() {
                row_data.push($(this).text());
            });
            // you'll need a reference to your DataTable here
            var table = $('#bega-data-tables').DataTable();
            table.row.add(row_data).draw();
        });

Comment: If you initialize your DataTable like this: `var table = $('#example').DataTable();` then `table` will be reference to your DataTable object you can use to call DataTable methods. The [API docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) are pretty comprehensive and do a good job of explaining this I think.

Comment: Ok, my english is not the best , so i will try to figure it out :P thanks anyway mate !

Comment: where i have to put the var table = $('#example').DataTable(); ?

i already have initlialized the plugin with 

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#foo).DataTable( {
            "paging":   false,
            "info":     false
        });
});

Comment: @151RUM I updated the answer to include an example of initializing the plugin and setting the DataTable object to a var. Does this make sense?

Comment: Good Morning @twernt. Yes it makes sense now :)

Everything works fine beside the fact, that the td's with the classes delete and copy are empty in the duplicated row. These two classes have an image inside which is not transfered. I think the .text() is the problem because it doenst return classes or images, right ?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it is still the best answer. Is there a way to also copy the hidden columns. so when display is changed the correct data td line up to the appropriate columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery that adds a row duplicate right underneath it, where DataTables is concerned. It has a caveat that this method may not retain any sorting or filtering set by the user.

```
$('#formtable tbody').on( 'click', 'button.btn-success', function () {
    //destroy instance of DataTables    
    table.destroy(false);

    //script assumes button is clicked on the line that needs to be duplicated
    var btn = this;

    //copy and insert row right below the original
    var line = $(btn).parents('tr');
    line.after(line.clone());

    //since clone retains only input field values, but not dropdown selections,
    //each dropdown value must be assigned individually
    line.next().find("select.shape").val(line.find("select.shape").val());
    line.next().find("select.material").val(line.find("select.material").val());
    line.next().find("select.supplied").val(line.find("select.supplied").val());

    //re-creating DataTables instance 
    //notice that "table" has no "var" in front - that's because it is pre-defined.
    table = $('#formtable').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": "_all"
        } ],
        "paging":   false,
        "info": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "searching": false,
        "rowReorder": true
    }); 
    //"Index Column" values re-calculation
    table.column(0).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this:

**HTML**

```
<table id="foo" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>Foo1</td>
      <td>Foo2</td>
      <td>Foo3</td>
      <td class="delete">IMAGE src here</td>
      <td class="duplicate"><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#foo tbody').on( 'click', 'tr .delete', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
    } );

$('#foo tbody').on( 'click', 'tr .duplicate', function () {
        var myTr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var clone = myTr.clone();
        myTr.after(clone);
    } );
```

Comment: naaa this will just be a UI change, if you filter or paginate the new row will no longer be there

Comment: Hmm unfortunately this is the only solution who works right now... but as you said Reddy, we need to filter results later on, so maybe this wont work in the end.